# How to run Dockerized React application in SSR (Server Side Rendering) mode

Tags: reactjs, .net, docker, server-side-rendering

I have a React application which runs on Docker container and interacts with .NET Core application running on another container. I want to run my React application in SSR (Server Side Rendering) mode. How can I do it? Should I install Nextjs in React application container?

Comment: i'm trying to understand.. what does Docker have to do with SSR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do server side rendering you have to use a nodejs image for your task.Easiest way to do server side rendering is use of static server.

example dockerfile for server side rendering:

```
FROM node:16 

# Create src directory 
WORKDIR /usr/src/

RUN npm init
RUN npm install -g serve

# adding bundle file to working dir
COPY . ./build

EXPOSE 3000 

# start static server
RUN serve -s build
```

If want to do clientside rendering you can build your docker image from nginx. first you have to build your react app. See the following

example dockerfile  for client side rendering :

```
FROM nginx:alpine

# adding nginx.conf file to the right place
COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

#remove default html file
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

#Copy index.html to nginx/html dir (this is the first thing request by browser)
COPY --from=builder /react-ui/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 3000 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Actually I'm doing the same but I was not sure that it renders on server side